# I want to create subdirectories that have the same name as the files I am going to move to them, using a batch file

Tags: windows-7, windows

For a given numeric filename, there are several files that exist in a directory.  This directory has hundreds of these numeric filenames.  I want to create a folder for each of the numeric file names and move the files into their respective folder.
I started out with:

```
  SET /P M= ENTER THE FOUR-DIGIT FILENAME
  MKDIR "%M%"
  MOVE "%M%.*" "%M%"
```

This works fine but I have to enter each filename.  Is there a way to allow the user to enter only the first two numbers of the filename so that I can create folders and move the files, 100 at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Next script should work for you. Basic explanation by `rem` comments. [Further info](http://ss64.com/nt/) on [`for` loop commands](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html), on [substrings](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html), on [`~` parameter modifier](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) etc.

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SET /P "M=ENTER THE TWO-DIGIT FILENAME "
    rem ensure 2-digit
set "M=00%M%"
    rem get last two characters
set "M=%M:~-2%"
for /L %%I in (0,1,9) do (
    for /L %%J in (0,1,9) do (
            rem here %M%%%I%%J = four-digit name
            rem exists at least one file starting with that 4 digits?
        if exist "%M%%%I%%J*.*" (
                rem create directory; error message throw away by 2>NUL
            MKDIR "%M%%%I%%J" 2>NUL
                rem move all files starting with 4 digits
                rem      but exclude directories by /a:-d
            for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /b /a:-d "%M%%%I%%J*.*"') do ( 
                MOVE "%%~G" "%M%%%I%%J\"
            )
        )
    )
)
```